# ASP.NET 5 JWT Token validation in resource server

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, asp.net-core, jwt

i have created an **authentication server** using `asp.net 5 rc-1` and `JWT tokens`

this is my `startup.cs` code

```
var key = new RsaSecurityKey(new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048).ExportParameters(true));
TokenAuthOptions tokenOptions = new TokenAuthOptions()
{
    Audience = "webappname",
    Issuer = "http://webappname.com",
    Key = key,
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512Signature)
};

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = tokenOptions.Key;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateSignature = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;

    options.TokenValidationParameters.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0);
});
```

and created a MVC Controller `OAuthController.cs` in same project to get the token

```
[HttpGet, Route("Signin")]
public dynamic Signin(string un, string pw)
{
    if (valid user)
    {
        DateTime? expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
        var token = GetToken(un, expires);
        return new { authenticated = true, entityId = 1, token = token, tokenExpires = expires };
    }
    return new { authenticated = false };
}

private string GetToken(string user, DateTime? expires)
{
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(user, "TokenAuth"), new[] { new Claim("EntityID", "1", ClaimValueTypes.Integer) });

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin2"));

    var securityToken = handler.CreateToken(
            issuer: _tokenOptions.Issuer,
            audience: _tokenOptions.Audience,
            signingCredentials: _tokenOptions.SigningCredentials,
            subject: identity,
            expires: expires
        );
    return handler.WriteToken(securityToken);
}
```

now when i call method `Signin` with username and password i'm getting jwt token in response and it can able to access the `[Authorize("Bearer", Roles="Admin2")]` controller methods in the same application.

How can i use the same token to **authenticate different application**?

Answer (score 0):

Your second app just needs access to the same RSA key that was used to sign the token.  Then you can use the token in your second app by configuring app.UseJwtBeaerAuthentication method the exact same way as the first app.